# I'm Trying to allow multiple user to use jupyter lab for coding online on my website

Tags: python-3.x, django, jupyter-lab

I want to allow the user to log in to my Django app and have their code separately and should not be allowed to delete the code/Folder/Files which they have not created.
For each user, the code should get saved separately

Here is the git repository of my tried code https://github.com/Rajput612/django-jupyterlab

Any Help Or guidance will be a great help as I want to create this for people who don't have the laptop at their disposal.

Comment: Have you heard about [JupyterHub](https://jupyter.org/hub) and [Binder](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) projects? They seem to do exactly that.

Other than "it already exists", this question lacks focus as of now. It might get closed as such unless it is improved to ask for a more specific aspect.

Comment: may i know what is the confusion here .....i would like to clearify it

Comment: i have heard of jupyterhub but i wassnt able to embed it in my website